# How can I prevent a button from getting resized when adding user control to form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tab control and a user control with a button. When I add the user control to the tab with this code:

```
ProductImporters uc = new ProductImporters();
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabProducts.Controls.Add(uc);
uc.Show();
uc.BringToFront();
```

The button grows a lot. I've already tried setting the button with a max-size, auto-size in false, I tried fixing and locking it, nothing works.

The user control is the same size of the tab where it is going to be put in.

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DockStyle.Fill use DockStyle.None. Use Anchoring to fix the position of the button. For example, anchor to right and bottom to fix it on the bottom right position.
Set Autosize property of the button to false. This will avoid resize.

Comment: I combined this with Auto scale mode in Dpi for the user control and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the font sizes from growing as well? The Auto size property for labels is not helping

Comment: I use containers like tableLayout to hold the labels and anchor my labels to fill the container, but I set the Autosize property of the container to false.
This may help you but it really depends on the settings for your label. What are the properties (Autosize, anchor, dock etc) for your label?